# How can we generate Stream sharable link in agora?

Tags: reactjs, stream, share, agora.io

how can we make a sharable link of stream in agora so that we can share it and other people can join it. Agora provides any kind of feature so that we can generate a stream link???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed these parameters as you would embed any other query parameter.

Example URL: https://example.com/?channel=cha123&appid=183432424242

In JavaScript:

```js
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let channel = params.get('name'); // is the string "cha123".
let appid = params.get('appid'); // is the string "183432424242"
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams